# Azure : How to i get the Refresh Token ? using Curl when the Output of the connection only gives Access Token

Tags: azure, authentication, curl, access-token, refresh-token

I am unable to get Refresh Token using Azure Service Principal (using Client ID & Client Secret)

Kindly help me in getting the refresh token via CURL and how to use it.

When i run the below CURL command in Windows CMD Prompt, i am getting Access Token. Whereas i am not getting refresh token along with it.

am i missing something here ?

Input :

```
curl -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/12345/oauth2/token ^
-F grant_type=client_credentials ^
-F resource=https://management.core.windows.net/ ^
-F client_id=12345-abcde ^
-F client_secret=12345abcde
```

Output:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1554368330",
    "not_before": "1554364430",
    "resource": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
    "access_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

As the output doesn't have refresh token (how do i get it)

Kindly requesting for any possible insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get refresh tokens with client id and secret. It doesn't make sense. Refresh tokens only make sense when a user is involved. Since there it allows you to get new tokens without prompting the user to login again.

You don't need a refresh token. You can get new tokens with client id and secret when you want.

Comment: I think @juunas is correct. Notice that you're using `client_credentials` as the `grant_type`. In case you're really interested in user based flow where refresh token would be valid, consider authorization code flow as described here.. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code .. On a side note, here is another SO thread which talks about Client Credentials grant and refresh tokens simply from OAuth standpoint (not specifically Azure AD's implementation) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340580/oauth-client-credential-flow-refresh-tokens

Comment: Many Thanks Juunas & Tony ju & Rohit Saigal

Comment: @juunas In my scenario users are involved. And I cannot redirect to the webpage every hour. So, I would need a refresh token. Any idea how do we implement that?

Comment: Which flow are you using? If implicit, you can use MSAL.js to refresh tokens automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Change the grant_type to 'password', add username and password to the request.

```
curl -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/12345/oauth2/token ^
-F grant_type=password ^
-F resource=https://management.core.windows.net/ ^
-F client_id=12345-abcde ^
-F client_secret=12345abcde ^
-F username=user@XX.onmicrosoft.com ^
-F password=******
```

You will be able to get the refresh_token.

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"scope": "User.ReadWrite.All",
"expires_in": "3600",
"ext_expires_in": "3600",
"expires_on": "1554711949",
"not_before": "1554708049",
"resource": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
"access_token": "******",
"refresh_token": "******"
}
```

You can use the refresh_token to [refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens).

Answer (score 0):

Given an existing `refresh token`, this request gets a new `access token` and a new `refresh token`, which one can use to iteratively fetch new ones before the expiration period, e.g. with a timer based process.

```
curl 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
     -H "Origin: https://localhost" \
     -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' \
     --data-raw "client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&refresh_token=${REFRESH_TOKEN}&grant_type=refresh_token&scope=openid%20profile%20User.Read%20offline_access"
```