# No refresh_token in Keycloak when POST request sent to demo client with POSTMAN

Tags: postman, keycloak, refresh-token

when I send a POST request to my demo client in keycloak, I get this:[image]

I also need a refresh token back in the response and I do not know where to find the refresh token in keycloak, any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340580/oauth-client-credential-flow-refresh-tokens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OAuth Client Credential Flow - Refresh Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340580/oauth-client-credential-flow-refresh-tokens)