# Getting Bad Request 400 while requesting for access token from refresh token Reddit API

Tags: access-token, reddit, refresh-token, reddit-access-token

Initially i'm getting access token for reddit api by using `payload={'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'duration': 'permanent'}` and this gives me **access_token** as well as **refresh token** and by using this refresh token, request for access_token but gives me Bad request  response.

```
url = "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token"

payload={'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
'refresh_token': '-_DdTnxTXtIVyoZPT9JzhUNq3bGRjRg'}
files=[

]
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'winserp',
  'Authorization': 'Basic *************************************************************************'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Response: `{'message': 'Bad Request', 'error': 400}`

Comment: perhaps you need to set the content-type and accept header to application/json in the header? as you are sending and receiving json data?

Comment: still same error @ToreNestenius 
i made content-type and accept to application/json in headers but still same error of Bad Request

Comment: @ToreNestenius initially i made a request to same url with different payload ```payload={'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'duration': 'permanent'}``` and getting access_token and refresh_token and then by using this refresh_token, i'm getting access_token with the above mentioned code but Bad Request error

Comment: Using client_credentials and refresh tokens does not make that much sense, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340580/oauth-client-credential-flow-refresh-tokens